# Spectra of matrices with null product

Tags: linear-algebra, products, matrix-decomposition

If I consider two square matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A B = B A =0$ and I know eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, is it possible to get informations about the spectrum of $B$?

In particular, I have to diagonalize operators (I only know that they are matrices of a fixed dimension) of the form $ A + B $ and I know the spectrum of $A$.

**EDIT:** I also know that $A$ and $B$ have the same set of eigenvalues, excluding at most a finite set. The thing I really need is to find the eigenvectors in a general way, without looking explicitly at the form of B.

Comment: You need to provide more conditions. If you take $B=0$, then you know all the eigenvalues & eigenvectors and the normality condition is trivial, but it can tell you nothing about $A$.

Comment: @copper.hat I have edited the question, it was a bit ambiguous. The only thing I know is that condition of "orthogonality" between the matrices.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, now I understood what you meant. It seems reasonable, thank you. In addition to that I know that they are hermitian matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices with $AB = 0$, then you know that any eigenvector $x$ of $A$ associated with $\lambda \neq 0$ satisfies $Bx = 0$.  That's about all you can say about eigenvalues.

As for eigenvectors: commuting Hermitian matrices share an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. If there are no repeated eigenvectors, then any eigenvector of one is an eigenvector of the other.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question with an additional detail.

Comment: See my latest edit